# Converting lower case to upper case

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column from lower case to upper case, but it is not working.

My code:

```
#Change all city name in city to uppercase.
library(magrittr)
city %>% `colnames<-`(tolower(names(name))) %>% head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your question completely, however if you are trying to convert text to upper case you should not use the **tolower()** function rather you should use the **toupper()** function.

For example:

```
toupper("A")
```

and if you want to make the column names uppercase I guess the syntax would be:

```
toupper(colnames(dataframe))
```

Comment: Yea I have a cab file named city.  In city.csv I have a Colname that is called name.  I want all data under that colname name to be upper.

Comment: in that case all you need to do is `colnames(dataframe) <- toupper(colnames(dataframe))`

Comment: didn't work.   colnames(city$name) <- toupper(colnames(city$name))

Comment: city[,2] = toupper(city[,2])   worked

Comment: Again your question was quite unclear, please try to be more clear.

Comment: It’s actually fixed.  The comment above resolved the changing from upper case to lower.  The site is not allowing me to put the solution in code form.   Thank you for the assistance.